# Remove line breaks and white spaces php

Tags: php

I have a string:

```
$str = '
            This Like a Somthing awesome text with 
   goods:Fb,Teleg,Top,Prods.fm,Ad-...
';
```

How I can remove spaces and line breaks? I want get this:

```
$str = 'This Like a Somthing awesome text with goods:Fb,Teleg,Top,Prods.fm,Ad-...';
```

A tried use:

```
trim($str);
```

But get same result.

Comment: I see no reason why trim() didn't work.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a combination of `trim` to remove leading and trailing whitespace, and `preg_replace` to replace all newlines and their surrounding spaces internal to the string with a single space:

```
$str = preg_replace('/\s*\R\s*/', ' ', trim($str));
echo $str;
```

Note in the above regex `\R` matches any newline (`\r`, `\n`) character.

Output:

```
This Like a Somthing awesome text with goods:Fb,Teleg,Top,Prods.fm,Ad-...
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/HFIWd)